# Having a user input an integer, or quitting by pressing 'q' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input, while-loop

I'm trying to have a user input an integer between 1 and variable ntopics, however including quitting by pressing 'q' causes issues. Running the following code only allows the user to quit, if "q" is the first input - it also only prints an error message for the user after the second input.

```
def get_non_negative_int_or_q(prompt):
    if input(prompt)=="q":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        while True:
                try:
                    value = int(input(prompt))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Integers only.")
                    continue
                if value < 1:
                    print(f"Sorry, your response must be an integer between 1 and {ntopics}.")
                    continue
                if value > ntopics:
                    print(f"Sorry, your response must be an integer between 1 and {ntopics}.")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
        return value


your_number = get_non_negative_int_or_q("Enter your number (or q to quit):")
```

The terminal will afterwards look like this:

````
Enter your number (or q to quit):r
Enter your number (or q to quit):r
Integers only.
Enter your number (or q to quit):r
Integers only.
Enter your number (or q to quit):q
Integers only.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the following block in your `while` loop:

```
if input(prompt)=="q":
    sys.exit()
```

You can do it the except block as:

```
while True:
     try:
         user_input = input(prompt)
         value = int(user_input)
     except ValueError:
         if user_input == "q":
             break # break out of loop
         else:
             print("Integers only.")
             continue
```